# Constructive Interference Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, acoustics, frequency, interference

> Two loudspeakers, 4 meters apart and facing each other, play identical sounds of the same frequency. You stand halfway between them, where there is a maximum of sound intensity. Moving from this point towards one of the speakers, you encounter a minimum of sound intensity when you have moved 0.25 meters.
>
> a.) What is the frequency of the sound?
>
> b.) If the frequency is then increased while you remain 0.25 meters from the center, what is the first frequency for which that location will be of maximum sound intensity?

This problem is so simple, which is why I have no idea how I've been stuck on it for the past two hours. (Well first , I read it wrong, but still.) So far, I have found the $\Delta r$ value for the 0.25 meter position, yielding that $0.5=(m+1/2)\lambda$, yet whenever I try to continue from there I run into some contradiction or road block. I am constantly getting confused with the $m$ values, and overall I would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried drawing a diagram for yourself? When you moved 25 cm, you increased the phase of one wave and decreased the phase of the other by the same amount. For cancellation, the phase difference must be $\pi$, so the phase difference for one of the sources was $\frac{\pi}{2}$ which means you moved by $\frac14 \lambda$.

When you have that, and the speed of sound, you have the frequency.

Ramping up the frequency (remembering that the center is always in phase, and a maximum) you find that at some point the intensity at 0.25 m is a maximum. That means the two signals are in phase, and that the distance you are from the center must therefore be $\lambda/2$.

Can you figure it out from here?